# how to plot a Vertical Likert Line Chart with Categories by ggplot2 or highcharter?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-highcharter

I want to create a Vertical Likert Line Chart , is there anyway to plot it by ggplot2 or highcharter ？

here is the example chart:

[image]

data example :

```
value1 <- abs(rnorm(26))*2
data <- data.frame(
  x=LETTERS[1:26], 
  value1=value1, 
  value2=value1+1+rnorm(26, sd=1) 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  pivot_longer(-x) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, value, color = name, group = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  coord_flip()
```

P.S. --- Since ggplot2 3.3.0 from March 2020, you can skip the "coord_flip" step and describe the axes directly in the orientation you want them, but the `geom_line` step still needs a nudge to display correctly:

```
...
ggplot(aes(value, x, color = name, group = name)) +
  geom_line(orientation = "y") +
  geom_point()
```

[image]